# PHP search box not linking to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have followed a video on Youtube explaining how to create a database with mySQL and how to create a search box to extract data from the database and display it to the webiste users. However, when I try and search for something in my database, it is telling me there are no results found. Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['search']))  {
header("Location:index.php");
}
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM 'Essays3' WHERE 'Essay Title' LIKE'%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0)  {
$search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
?>

<p>Search Results:</p>
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) !=0)  {
do { ?>
<p><?php echo $search_rs['Essay Title']; ?></p>


<?php   } while ($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
} else {
echo "No Results Found";
}   ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="searchbox" method="post" action="search.php">
<input name="search" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

My database is callled Essays3 and the table created is called Essays. One of the collumns is called Essay Title which is what I am trying to search for.

Comment: how can you column name have space ?

Answer (score 0):

If your table is called Essays, your query should be

```
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM Essays WHERE `Essay Title` LIKE'%".$_POST['search']."%'";
```

Attention to the column name quotation.

On another topic, your code is pretty outdated. Take a look at http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers or [this search on youtbe](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php%20data%20objects%20pdo&sm=3). PDO is the right way to use databases on php these days.

Answer (score 0):

You really should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements (to fix the sql injection problem you have) and add error handling.

However, it seems in this case that the problem is caused by the wrong kind of quotes. If you need to quote a table- or column name because it contains spaces, you need to use backticks:

```
$search_sql="SELECT * FROM `Essays3` WHERE `Essay Title` LIKE'%".$_POST['search']."%'";
```